# Framework issue - Module file was created by an older version of the compiler

Tags: swift, frameworks, openx

I'm using

- newest OpenXSDKframework (debug)
- included in embedded Binaries
- Build Settings: Embedded Content Contains Swift Code YES
- Other linker -Objc
- XCode 7.31
- swift

when **import OpenXSDKCore** 
this error is showing

> .../ViewController/OpenXBannerViewController.swift:11:8: **Module file
>   was created by an older version of the compiler;**
>
> rebuild 'OpenXSDKCore' and try again:
>   .../OpenXSDKCore.framework/Modules/OpenXSDKCore.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule

is this related to the Framework producing Company ?

what should i do - to fix that error?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error will occur if the compiled framework (binary) was compiled using earlier version of compiler and in the most of the iOS cases it means that the binary was compiled using some earlier versions of Xcode.

Most probably, your `OpenXSDKCore` was not built using Xcode 7.3 that you use. The best course of action would be downloading the framework source code and **compiling it by yourself**.

If you don't have that option you can only wait or downgrade to earlier Xcode version.